# Samples are currently unavailable for: {Symbol: Fragment, Package: android.support.v4.app} in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

From Android studio 2.2 Preview, Google-provided Android code samples based on the currently highlighted symbol in your project. To use the feature, highlight a Variables, Types and Methods in your code then Right Click to show a context menu for Find Sample Code.

```
[http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/05/android-studio-22-preview-new-ui.html][1]
```

When I tried this future I am getting Samples are currently unavailable for Fragment,AppCompatActivity,Toolbar, FloatingActionButton.

Do we need to download samples or enable it from settings, how can I get this future ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download samples from the SDK Manager.

Check the following link for reference.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sdk_manager.htm

Comment: I have downloaded samples, still i am not getting suggestions.

Comment: I have the same issue and this article doesn't help